# Get attribute values at beginning and end of a date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database table **stockmovements** with columns DATE, PRODUCT, UNITS,TYPE, STOCK. STOCK saves the value of stock at that date when a certain stock movement was done. TYPE can be purchase or sold or return.

I group by product so that any row of the table in my view shows a product. Then I want to create 2 columns. Stock start and stock end. Showing stock values at the first and last date of a date range. So that later let say I apply I filter 1st october - 31st october the 2 columns will show stock value at 1st october and stock value at 31st october.

If no filters are applied columns will show stock value of earliest and latest stockmovement among all values in database.

And in the middle columns to show units for each stockmovement type. So that in the end will be product, stock start, purchased, sold, returned, stock end. This is just to give an idea about the general logic but it doesn't really matter for the question.

I have this in my controller:

```
@stockmovements = Stockmovement.all.group(:PRODUCT)
```

What should I add to my view:

```
 <td><%= number_to_human stockmovement.STOCK, precision: 0 %></td>
```

to get the stock values at beginning and end of the date range? Or should this be done in the model? I basically need STOCK where DATE= start date and STOCK where DATE= end date. But I can't find any helper to do that.

Comment: If you can change it, you should make your columns lower case (e.g. "date, product, units, type, stock").  But my main question is, when you say STOCK saved the value of the stock by "value" you mean stock quantity * unit price?  Is it the value before or after the current movement?

Comment: I'm building an app on existing database so I cannot change the database. No STOCK is same as sum(UNITS). That's the value after the current movement. Imagine columns PRODUCT, UNITS, STOCK. I make a purchase | Product A, 3, 3 | then I make a sale |
Product A, -1,2 |.

Comment: What I mean is that it doesn't need any calculation. I'm just building a report. I just need to read those values as they are in database. And I just need to show them at those 2 dates.

Comment: Right, ok, then for the "start" column you really want STOCK - UNITS of the first record (the opening value). ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Well I need STOCK only. I don't need the value of UNITS for the first or last record..

Comment: STOCK column could be MOOD column with angry or happy or mad for what matters. And I'd need the mood for the first date and the end date. I just need the value on the row corresponding to first record and last record.

Comment: Ok, but if the view is meant to really show stock opening value, movement,s and closing value then opening value can't just be represented as "MOOD" or "COLOUR" or whatever... it won't show the opening value of the product, it'll show the opening value of the product after the first transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a hash of values, {location => [opening_value, closing_value]}

```
# replace following with whatever dates you need, probably 
# from params (input form)

from_date = DateTime.parse('2016-10-01')
to_date = DateTime.parse('2016-10-31').end_of_day 

@stockopenclose = {}

products = Stockmovement.where('DATE >= ? AND DATE <= ?',from_date, to_date).pluck(:product).uniq.sort

products.each do |product|

  movements = Stockmovement.where('DATE >= ? AND DATE <= ? AND PRODUCT = ?',from_date, to_date, product)

  opening_value = movements.sort('DATE ASC').limit(1).pluck('STOCK').first
  closing_value = movements.sort('DATE DEC').limit(1).pluck('STOCK').first

  @stockopenclose[product] = [opening_value, closing_value]

end
```

You can then reference `<%= @stockopenclose[location][0] %>` for opening value and  `<%= @stockopenclose[location][1] %>` for closing, assuming your iterating by location.

But there are a few problems...

The STOCK at opening value will be the value AFTER the first movement was applied, so it won't be a true opening value. I think the opening would need to be...

```
stock, units = movements.sort('DATE ASC').limit(1).pluck('STOCK', 'UNITS').first
opening_value = stock.to_i - units.to_i
```

Second, this doesn't handle slow moving stocks, i.e. stocks with no activity in the period don't appear on the list, so if this report is an inventory analysis it's deficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right about the opening value I didn't consider that. About products with no activity not showing in the list that's fine. The only useful value for those would be stock but I have another report for that. Ok I need a while to understand your solution. I'll let you know soon.

Comment: Sorry the column is actually a datetime with values like 2015-02-16 11:38:03 UTC. Does that affect your solution? Because now I'm getting undefined local variable or method `from_date' for.....

Comment: I didn't specify `from_date` or `to_date` because I assumed that would be set by you... I've modified my answer to show how it might be set...

Comment: Ok it's clearer now I  was trying to understand if those were a sort of helpers but I get it now.  I'm using ransack so I need to find a way to integrate it with your solution. Those values can't be static. One thing I can't really understand is the iterating by location part. I need to read more about iterating an array..I'll be back tomorrow.

Comment: I am getting `undefined local variable or method `location' for #<#<Class:0x007f6d08905598>` although I have a column LOCATION in stockmovements and a table locations with a module Location . But honestly I don't really understand what that part in view is doing so it's hard to fix. Could you please explain more if it's not too bother?

Comment: Hi, we haven't talked about `LOCATION` so that's some other part of the code, but if you look at the full stack trace you'll be able to identify what line of code is complaining... it'll be something like app/views/_form.html.erb:45  where it's telling you line 45 is where the problem arose. I'd need to see the stack trace.  Can you post this as a new question and let me know when you have?